# Multiple regression in R: How to get error terms for new predictor data $X$ to predict $Y?$

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, residuals

I am running a simple multiple regression model in R lm package. The equation is

$\log(Y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\log(x_{1i}) + \beta_2\log(x_{2i}) + \beta_3(x_{3i}) + e_i$,

where one intercept $\beta_0$ is estimated for the full sample, and the residuals $e_i$ vary across observations i=1,...10000. Using the `lm` package and `summary(lmfit)`, I got all $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, and $\betaβ_3$. $e_i$ are the `lmfit$residuals` ($Y_i$ - fitted values).

My question is, given a new set of $x_{1j}$, $x_{2j}$, $x_{3j},\; (j=1,...,100),$ I want to predict $Y_j$ and no observations of $Y$ exist. How can I estimate the residuals $e_j$ from these $e_i$ estimates so that I can use the new equation below:

$\log(Y_j) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\log(x_{1j}) + \beta_2\log(x_{2j}) + \beta_3(x_{3j}) + e_j?$

I will appreciate any suggestions in the context of R. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you would like to plug new data into a model. This can be accomplished with the predict() function in R.  This post goes over it in detail https://www.journaldev.com/45290/predict-function-in-r. To get the new residuals, you would just manually calculate the MSE of the new predictions with the actual Y values for the new data.

Comment: @TannerPhillips Thanks for your comment. I think what you talked about is a prediction  "without" the residual term. I can get the prediction from log(Yj)=β0+β1log(x1j)+β2log(x2j)+β3(x3j) without the residual, but I don't have the actual Y values for the new X1, X2, and X3. My purpose is to get more accurate predicted Y, so that's why I want to see if I can estimate ej for X1j, X2j, and X3j. I just revise my question at the end. Is this clearer to you?

Comment: In the most common linear model, when you suppose the error terms are independent and normally distributed with variance $\sigma^2$, the residuals are noise. You cannot get the residuals $e_j$ from the residuals $e_i$. What you can do, and that idea is incorporated in prediction intervals, is estimate the variance $\sigma^2$ as $\hat{\sigma}^2 = RSS/(n-p)$, where RSS is the residual sum of squares you get from the fitted model. This gives you an idea of how far your predictions may be from the true values.

Comment: @JosePliego This is very helpful. I kind of remembered that the prediction intervals are based on the combined effect of of intercept intervals and intervals of the coefficients β1,...βn, but I did not know that include the error term $e_i$. I also found that people are talking about the Heteroskedasticity and robust covariance matrix. I look at the residuals $e_i$ and they seem to be heteroskedastic. In this case, is this variance RSS/(n-p) still good to use?

Comment: When you have heteroskedasticity, using that estimate may yield overly optimistic intervals. If you want to incorporate non-constant variance terms take a look at the Weighted Least Squares method. Also worth mentioning, the estimator $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is often RSS/(n-p-1) to make it unbiased, but it makes no difference for big n.

Comment: If you wanted to attempt to quantify the error, you can at, "interval = predict" to the predict() funciton. But what others here have stated is correct-- residuals are entirely a theoretical component of the regression formula, and if you plug new data into a regression formula, there is no way to know the residuals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable inputs. I will play around the interval.